# What is the best practice of passing reference counted C++ objects to Lua?

Tags: c++, lua, reference-counting

I want to have my reference counted C++ object also managed in Lua callbacks: when it is held by a Lua variable, increase its refcount; and when the Lua variable is destroyed, release one refcount. It seems the releasing side can be automatically performed by `__gc` meta-method, but how to implement the increasing side?

Is it proper&enough to just increase refcount every time before adding the object to Lua stack?

Or maybe I should *new* a smart pointer object, use it everywhere in Lua C function, then delete it in `__gc` meta-method? This seems ugly as if something wrong with the Lua execution and the `__gc` is not called, the *new*ed smart pointer object will be leaked, and the refcounted object it is referring would have leak one count.

In **Perl** that I'm more familiar with, this can be achieved by increase refcount at `OUTPUT` section of *XS Map*, and decrease refcount at destroyer.

Comment: `if something wrong with the Lua execution and the __gc is not called, ... would have leak one count` - This means you should terminate your application when Lua VM crashed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have implemented two Lua functions in C: `inc_ref_count(obj)` and `dec_ref_count(obj)`

```lua
local MT = {__gc = dec_ref_count}
local setmetatable = setmetatable
local T = setmetatable({}, {__mode="k"})

function register_object(obj)
   if not T[obj] then
      T[obj] = setmetatable({}, MT)
      inc_ref_count(obj)
   end
end
```

Invoke `register_object(object)` on C side every time you send a ref-counted C object to Lua

You may leak memory if Lua VM crashed or was closed.

Answer (score 0):

After more study on Lua manual, I found that light user data does not support metatable (see [document](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#lua_pushlightuserdata)). It should be implemented via heavy user data ([lua_newuserdatauv](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#lua_newuserdatauv)) that allocates a chunk of memory by Lua machine. I can placement new a smart pointer object using this memory chunk, and bind a `__gc` on it.